# How to implement multi dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

[image]I have called a service through ajax and got a list of values and i have parsed the values as js object in below line

```
   var parseviewpresctiption = $.parseJSON(viewprescription);
```

i have an array of 20 values as json object which has value in each object.but the value in different object belong to single question id.So i need to group the value and based on the id and store it in multi dimensional array.in my above code i have declared a multi dimensional array but i could not able to store the value in array and it is throwing the error.

```
   var questions = {};
   for(var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
   questions[questionId][i] = {
                'questionId' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].option.optionId,
                'column' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].option.content,
                'row' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].question.content,
                'value' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].text,
                'table' : tableTypeName,
                'answerId' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].answerId
                          }
             };
```

If i remove the multi dimensional array like

```
           questions[questionId][i] = {
                'questionId' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].option.optionId,
                'column' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].option.content,
                'row' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].question.content,
                'value' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].text,
                'table' : tableTypeName,
                'answerId' : parseviewpresctiption[prop].answerId
                          }
```

the last value with that id is getting stored in the array.How to declare a multi dimensional array and group the values based on the id

i need to get the value and append the value in single table row

Sample data
                    Object
answerId
:
968
doctor
:
null
option
:
Object
content
:
"N/A"
optionId
:
8
**proto**
:
Object
patient
:
Object
numVisits
:
0
patientId
:
66
rdoUser
:
Object
vipScore
:
0
**proto**
:
Object
question
:
Object
content
:
"Personal Physician Last Name"
help
:
null
option
:
null
question
:
null
questionId
:
43
questionType
:
"TXT"
**proto**
:
Object
questionnaireTemplate
:
Object
description
:
"Current Medical Problems"
name
:
"MEDICAL_HISTORY"
questionnaireTemplateId
:
12
rdoUser
:
Object
shared
:
false
**proto**
:
Object
sequenceNumber
:
null
text
:
"S"

Comment: Can you provide a sample data that's being passed to `viewprescription`?

Comment: i have added the sample data in which u have ans as text "S" for question id 43 and option id 8 same question id with diff option id for ex 9 contain different value in text so i have to declare a multi dimentional array which store the value questions[43][0]='s' questions[43][1]='T'

Comment: It looks like you want an _Object_ where the names of it's properties are _IDs_ and the values of it's properties are _Arrays_.

Comment: Can you try to format your sample data better? Since the `viewprescription` variable seems to be just JSON-formatted string, it would be great to just add a sample JSON data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array map` method instead.

```
var questions = parseviewpresctiption.map(function(v) {
                    return {
                      questionId : v.option.optionId,
                      column : v.option.content,
                      row : v.question.content,
                      value: v.text,
                      table : tableTypeName, //I'm assuming that you
                      answerId: v.answerId
                    };
                });
```

This will return array of objects. *Sorry for the late reply mate!*

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` method, You should check this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). 
 Can you just `console.log` response and drop the screenshot here, It's hard to figure out from the data sample you've posted.